# Improving your Work Experience Outside of Work

Tags: career-development

My current programming job is not very interesting and I am not learning anything new.  If I find a position I am interested in,  I don't think my current experience is going to help me much in the interview.  I talked to my boss about this and I don't think things are going to change.

Do you have any good recommendations of things to do outside of work to build my resume and portfolio?

Comment: Program on your own time? Learn new programming languages to expand your resume? Freelance work?

Comment: Its up to you to maintain your marketability. There are a ton of free online resource that can help you. Take a look at current jobs in your area, see what technology is popular and to your taste, pick one or two and get rolling with the learning.

Comment: I guess experience would be a better word to use than portfolio.  I still want to be a programmer, I just don't like the current work I do and my current company.

Comment: What technologies interest you?

Comment: Javascript, Python, AWS, Github, Ubuntu, Ruby, Docker, Spring Boot, MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** - Start looking and applying for jobs. Experience isn't everything. This will also help you for my second point.

**Second** - Start learning things in your own time. Either look for free resources or sign up to PluralSight or something similar. See what skills jobs you have applied for/looked at want and that you currently lack and learn those.

It sounds like you are still quite a junior developer (apologies if not). If this is the case, applying for jobs when you don't tick every single box doesn't mean you won't stand a chance of getting it.

When hiring junior developers, people look for:

1. Core Knowledge - What does this person know at this moment
2. Learning new tech - How quickly will it take this person to learn java/css etc
3. Will this person fit into the team

Now, for 1, you should hopefully have that. If not work on it.

For 3, you can't really help that, so just be you and somewhere you'll fit in.

Point 2 is the key one. If you can interview and say, oh I've been looking at x and y recently and can go into a reasonable bit of technical detail, then it demonstrates number 2. Even if x and y aren't what the new company are looking for, it demonstrates that you are willing and able to get up to speed quicker than others.

Whilst learning, you can setup a GitHub account and show some code samples etc too, to help "prove" you have been looking at x and y. This would help with a portfolio of sorts.

Comment: I am closer to a mid level developer (4 years experience) . Does that affect your answer?

Comment: Not really. But maybe have a bit more belief in yourself. Go for jobs. The worst they will say is no thanks. Other things you could do are contribute to github projects also

Comment: + GitHub mentioned